# Ошибка библиотеки Google Drive flysystem-google-drive в Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-drive

Я захостил свой тестовый проект Laravel на Heroku, но, поскольку он не поддерживает загрузку файлов, мне пришлось использовать Google Drive. Для этого я установил [этот](https://github.com/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive) пакет (flysystem-google-drive) и сделал все, что было рекомендовано в [этом](https://maxyc.ru/programming/laravel/storage-google-drive-laravel/) руководстве. Но даже при установке пакета flysystem, composer выдал либо предупреждение, либо ошибку, код которой я привел ниже. Что это и как исправить есть идеи?

UPD. Пробовал делать как рекомендуют [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701156/class-google-client-not-found) (добавив classmap в composer.json autoload), но безрезультатно. После этого вылазит новая ошибка:

`[RuntimeException] Could not scan for classes inside “vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google” which does not appear to be a file nor a folder`

```
Class Google_Service_Adsense_AdClientAdCode located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\AdClientAdCode.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_AdUnitAdCode located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\AdUnitAdCode.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Cell located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Cell.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ContentAdsSettings located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ContentAdsSettings.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Date located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Date.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Header located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Header.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_HttpBody located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\HttpBody.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListAccountsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListAccountsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListAdClientsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListAdClientsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListAdUnitsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListAdUnitsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListAlertsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListAlertsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListChildAccountsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListChildAccountsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListCustomChannelsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListCustomChannelsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListLinkedAdUnitsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListLinkedAdUnitsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListLinkedCustomChannelsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListLinkedCustomChannelsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListPaymentsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListPaymentsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListSavedReportsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListSavedReportsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListSitesResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListSitesResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ListUrlChannelsResponse located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ListUrlChannelsResponse.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_ReportResult located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\ReportResult.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Resource_AccountsAdclientsAdunits located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Resource\AccountsAdclientsAdunits.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Resource_AccountsAdclientsCustomchannels located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Resource\AccountsAdclientsCustomchannels.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Resource_AccountsAdclientsUrlchannels located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Resource\AccountsAdclientsUrlchannels.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Resource_AccountsSites located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Resource\AccountsSites.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Row located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Row.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_Site located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\Site.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense_TimeZone located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense\TimeZone.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Google_Service_Adsense located in D:/OpenServer/domains/Laravel_store/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src\Google\Service\AdSense.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

Comment: Могу предложить свою обёртку над Google Drive (https://github.com/w3lifer/google-drive), так как ваш вариант воспроизвести трудно. Чтобы показывать загруженные изображения например, можно это прочесть: https://dev.to/imamcu07/embed-or-display-image-to-html-page-from-google-drive-3ign.
P. S. Попробуйте кэш почистить: `composer clearcache` и проверить версию PHP.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! С этим я разобрался, добавил в composer.json autoload ссылку на apiclient-services и заработало, однако теперь появилось что то другое, что у автора статьи не было, возможно сталкивались, ошибку я описал тут, правда на англоязычном SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237579/refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccesstoken-laravel?noredirect=1#comment118848779_67237579